# UniData External Data Access (EDA) synchronization

Tags: data-synchronization, unidata, external-data-access

Is it a good idea to continuously use External Data Access (EDA) for synchronization of big files (let's say with 10 million records) with RDBMS. Will EDA also handle incremental updates to the source UniData file and automatically reflect those changes(CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE) to the target RDBMS system?
Also, according to the documentation, EDA supports right now MSSQL, Oracle and DB2. Is it possible to configure EDA to work for example with PostgreSQL?